# size for "Event_Mask" too small, minimum allowed is 64

Tags: linux, ada, ncurses, rhel

When I make `ncurses-5.9` in red hat linux, following issue occurred:

```
gcc -c -g -O2 -gnatafno -gnatVa -gnatwa -I- -gnatA /home/xiaodobl/ncurses-5.9/Ada95/src/terminal_interface-curses-mouse.adb
```

Error is:

> terminal_interface-curses-mouse.ads:180:10: size for "Event_Mask" too small, minimum allowed is 64

How to solve the issue?

Comment: A good starting point would be to show the code surrounding terminal_interface-curses-mouse.ads:180:10, and more specifically, all code defining the Event_Mask in question. We are happy to help, but can't read your screen from here...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the relevant declarations in `terminal_interface-curses-mouse.ads`, I can't tell for sure.  However, I suspect that there's a conflict in the size of `Event_Mask`.  When I tried it, this line was hard-wired into `terminal_interface-curses-mouse.ads.m4`:

```
type Event_Mask is new Interfaces.C.unsigned_long;
```

but the rep clause for `Mouse_Event` defines `Bstate`, of type `Event_Mask`, like this:

```
Bstate  at 0 range 128 .. 159;
```

This is based on the type of `mmask_t` in `<ncurses.h>`, which is `unsigned` on my system.  If `unsigned_long` is 64 bits and C's `unsigned` type is 32, the compiler will complain.

If this is what's happening, try manually changing the `type Event_Mask` line to

```
type Event_Mask is new Interfaces.C.unsigned_long range 0 .. 2**32 - 1;
for Event_Mask'Size use 32;
```

or

```
type Event_Mask is new Interfaces.C.unsigned_long range 0 .. 2**32 - 1 with Size => 32;
```

which hopefully will avoid the "size too small" problem without causing any new type conflicts in the rest of the code.  However, I haven't tested it.

This should be reported as a bug since the type of `Event_Mask` shouldn't be hardwired like this.

**EDIT:** It didn't occur to me until later that since `Event_Mask` is a derived type, there's no benefit to deriving it from `Interfaces.C.unsigned_long` with a range constraint.  Assuming `mmask_t` is defined as `unsigned` in the `.h` file, it should work just as well to say

```
type Event_Mask is new Interfaces.C.unsigned;
```

You still have to change it manually, and really the `.m4` file and generator need to be fixed to figure out the right type, which is why I think this should be considered a bug in `ncurses`.

Comment: All of the above; but, reading `configure`, you *may* be able to get away with configuring with `--with-mmask-t=‘unsigned long’`.